# using <g:select> grails

Tags: grails, gsp, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I am using a  to display list of profilenames.

```
<g:select name="ProfileSelector" from='${ProfileList?.profileName}' id='ProfileSelect' noSelection="['null':' SELECT VT']" disabled="true" />
```

So profile list is type of profiles having profilename,profileid,profileDescription. On submit I was only able to access the profileName selected as param in the controller.Is there any way that I could pass the profileId of corresponding profileName as param.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by using the optionKey and optionValue parameters. Have a look at http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Tags/select.html for more info.